# Program only works if I manually press run each time, while loop does not work

Tags: python

```
import random


def ranCardNum():
    ranCardNumls = []
    for i in range(0,16):
        ranNum = random.randint(0,9)
        ranCardNumls.append(ranNum)
    return ranCardNumls
#Gets random 16 digits long number and adds it to a list
        


def luhnAlgo(NoPrPro):
    #print("".join(str(n) for n in NoPrPro))
    
    for i in range(14,0,-2):
        NoPrPro[i] = NoPrPro[i] * 2
        if NoPrPro[i] >= 10:
            first = str(NoPrPro[i])[0]
            second = str(NoPrPro[i])[1]  
            NoPrPri= int(first) + int(second)
            NoPrPro[i] = NoPrPri 
            
    return "".join(str(n) for n in NoPrPro)
#The luhn algorithm returns number without the list
        
def endDate():
    dateM = random.randint(1,12)
    if dateM <= 9:
        letter = str(dateM)
        dateM = "0" + letter
    dateY = random.randint(2022,2026)
    
    return dateM, dateY
#generates random dates and returns them
    
def ranCvv():
    ranCvv = random.randint(100,1000)
    return ranCvv
#random 3 digit number and returns it
    

def writeCsv(cardNum,cardDay, cardYear, cvv):
    f = open("cardNo.csv","a")
    f.write(cardNum + ",")
    f.write(cardDay + ",")
    f.write(cardYear + ",")
    f.write(cvv + "\r")
    f.close()
#writes to my csv file
#Check - Taken from geeksforgeeks.org
def checkLuhn(cardNo):
     
    nDigits = len(cardNo)
    nSum = 0
    isSecond = False
     
    for i in range(nDigits - 1, -1, -1):
        d = ord(cardNo[i]) - ord('0')
     
        if (isSecond == True):
            d = d * 2

        nSum += d // 10
        nSum += d % 10
  
        isSecond = not isSecond
     
    if (nSum % 10 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
cardNo = luhnAlgo(ranCardNum())

if __name__=="__main__": 
    if (checkLuhn(cardNo)):
        print(cardNo)
        expDay = str(endDate()[0])
        expYear = str(endDate()[1])
        cvv = str(ranCvv())
        writeCsv(cardNo, expDay,expYear, cvv)
    else:
        print("Not valid")
```

I am trying to put the check into a while loop but whenever I do that it'll only return Not valid.
I am not too sure why its doing this as it works when I manually run it. I want the program to run automatically and return a valid card number instead of me tapping run until it gives me a response. I'm sure it is a fairly simple issue but I have been stuck on it for a while and do not want to ask my teacher,
Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying it only prints Not valid once? Or does it print it indefinitely?

Comment: Please show the code you're having trouble with. We can't tell you what you're doing in the while loop if you don't show it.

Comment: Apologies for that, it continuously prints Not Valid if its in the while loop.

Comment: the part I am having issues with is within the if __name__ == "__main__":

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `while True:` and have a `break` when you get a valid card number and have written it to the file:

```py
if __name__=="__main__":
    while True:
        cardNo = luhnAlgo(ranCardNum())
        if (checkLuhn(cardNo)):
            print(cardNo)
            expDay = str(endDate()[0])
            expYear = str(endDate()[1])
            cvv = str(ranCvv())
            writeCsv(cardNo, expDay,expYear, cvv)
            break
        else:
            print("Not valid")
```

The `else: print("Not valid")` is just optional now.

**Update:**

While you are at it you might as well acknowledge in code that the expiry date has a year and a month (plus only one call to `endDate()` is needed):

```py
            expMon,expYear = endDate()
            cvv = str(ranCvv())
            writeCsv(cardNo, str(expMon), str(expYear), cvv)
```

If `ranCvv()` is supposed to generate 3 digit numbers, it should not risk generating a 4 digit number (the `randint()` function is a closed range):

```py
def ranCvv():
    ranCvv = random.randint(100, 999)
    return ranCvv
```

Comment: That's what I have already attempted but it simply wont return anything but Not valid.

Comment: When I run the code I’ve posted, it prints “Not valid” a few times, but always ends with writing to the file. Your code as posted is very likely to print “Not valid” and exit.